# Capture theme-related items on window

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

I am working on an application where i have to capture a screenshot of a window with the window of my application itself invisible (hiding it, making screenshot, then showing again is not an option due to number of reasons). I do it by walking over all top-level windows, building their z-order, and capturing the necessary area of them into a bitmap one by one. In general it works, except that things like X, minimize, and maximize buttons on the top-right of the window bar do not show up, they just look like a black box. I am assuming that this is because they are drawn by Windows itself without use of GDI, so they are simply not on the DC of the window, and i can't BitBlt() them.

Is there anything i can do about it? Except dirty tricks of course.

Comment: We can't see how you are doing this. We don't know what your code is. Please show a [mcve].

Answer (score -1):

I suspect you use 32bit bitmap (with alpha channel) to render the whole thing.

GDI does not support alpha in general and, what is worse, different GDI functions deal with alpha byte inconsistently.

Try to use 24bpp DIB for your destination bitmap to avoid inconsistencies.

Comment: That sounds like potentially working. Any idea how? Can you point me at the code snippet? And yes indeed, i am using bitmap with alpha channel.

Comment: "Code snippet" of what exactly ?